# I need to assign time value to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I need to assign a variable time value that is in particular cell.

I have tried assigning values differently but everytime it gives me mismatch error:

```
Sub country_despatch(i)

Dim tm As Double
Dim date1 As Double

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
While i < lRow

 date1 = Sheet1.Cells("B", i).Value
 display (date1)
Wend

End Sub
```

I need to assign cell `B2` value to `date1`. If the condition is met we move to next cell `B3` and assign its value to `date1` so on till the end of the rows.

Comment: Unrelated to your main issue, but I'd recommend using a `For...Next` loop instead of `While...Wend`. Also, declare `i`, and use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Hi BigBen. I need to assign date1 the value of time in cell B2. it is giving me type mismatch error

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code:

1. Row counting variables need to be `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle:
   `Dim lRow As Long`
2. Your parameter `i` has no type specified:
   `Sub country_despatch(StartRow As Long)`
3. In `Sheet1.Cells("B", i)` you mixed up rows and columns the correct syntax is
   `Cells(row, column)`
   `Sheet1.Cells(i, "B")`
4. You use `While i < lRow … Wend` but never increment `i` so this loop will run endless. Either use a `For iRow = StartRow To LastRow … Next iRow` loop that auto increments `iRow` or increment `i` manually by `i = i + 1` in your `While` loop.
5. I highly recommend to use `Option Explicit` and use meaningful variable names. If you need to start numbering variables you did something fundamentally wrong. Names like `ws1` and `ws2` are the worst choice. Use something meaningful like `wsSource` and `wsDestination` for example. This is much easier to understand and maintain, and you will have less errors if you don't mix up `ws1` and `ws2`.

   Also meaningful index variable names are extremly helpful. If you just name them `i` you never know if this is for row increments or column increments. If you name it `iRow` or `iColumn` it gets pretty clear.

So you should end up with something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    country_despatch StartRow:=2
End Sub

Sub country_despatch(ByVal StartRow As Long)
    Dim MyTime As Double
    Dim MyDate As Date

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = StartRow To LastRow
        MyDate = Sheet1.Cells(iRow, "B").Value 'value into date format
        MyTime = CDbl(MyDate) - CLng(MyDate) 'extract only the time from a date/time

        Debug.Print "date", MyDate, CDbl(MyDate)
        Debug.Print "time part", MyTime
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Make sure the values in your column B are real dates or times. If they are strings this might not work properly (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

change 
`this date1 = Sheet1.Cells("B", i).Value` to `date1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value`

you had swapped the row index and column index to Cells